# Changing user when running psql command on Mac terminal

Tags: terminal, psql

I installed PostgreSQL on my Mac (from their website) and set it up to have it run on my terminal using psql command. However, when I use psql command, it asks for password for my Mac user and when I enter the password, it returns password authentication error. I only have postgres set up as a user. When I run `psql -U postgres` and enter the password, I am connected to the database.

How can I change the default user to postgres instead of my Mac user (jp) so I can just use psql command? I have also included what I have in .bash_profile file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, but it seems that setting the environment variable `export PGUSER = "WUTONK"` in the terminal is useless， It still takes my local user name as the default connection user, even in the account where I have not registered this name in the PostgreSQL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).